# Do I need to pause a little after every ayah while reading during salah?

Tags: salat, sunni

I usually read a little fast and don't pause between the verses. Is it compulsory to pause between the verses if I am not combining them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Abu Dawood (4001) and at-Tirmidhi (2927) narrated that Umm Salamah
> said:*
>
> *The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon
> him) used to interrupt his recitation, so he would recite, “Al-hamdu
> Lillahi Rabb il-‘Aalameen (All the praises and thanks be to Allah, the
> Lord of the Alameen (mankind, jinns and all that exists)),” then
> pause; “ar-Rahmaan ir-Raheem (The Most Beneficent, the Most
> Merciful)”, then pause.*

Though this hadith is classed as Sahih by Albani(May Allah Have Mercy on Him) it is also classified Hasan by Ibn al-Jazari.

**It is also not compulsory to do so**, but some/most scholars agree upon this as Sunnah.
Contemplating on each verse and having full understanding could **improve your Kushoo** which in turn would improve your Salah.

Also according to IslamQA:

> "*However it is disallowed to stop reciting altogether at a particular
> point if that will change the meaning, such as one who recites the
> words “So woe unto those performers of Salat (prayers)” [al-Maa‘oon
> 107:4], and stops there without reciting the following verse.*"

Though do not rush your salat as you want your salat to be accepted so I advise you do each action(i.e Ruku, Sajdah, While standing and reciting, Transitions) carefully and with time.

I also realized I've been doing some aspects in my prayer wrong so I'd think it would be beneficial to watch some videos that are strictly according to the sunnah and see what micro-mistakes have been made. If no mistakes were made in your prayer then may Allah accept them.

Also don't forget the dua when starting salah.

you can find more examples from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLWJtXtmnbM&t=192s) video

Take more time each day that goes by and be of those who guard their prayers.

Source:
https://islamqa.info/en/229818

<sub>*May Allah help strengthen our prayers, And Allah knows best. May Allah
forgive me for any mistakes*</sub>